# Exception while using LoadFile() in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is ia piece of code from my powershell script:
`$PatchSummaryTextBox.LoadFile($ReadMeFilePath.FullName)`

`$PatchSummaryTextBox =  New-Object windows.forms.RichTextBox`
represents a text box in which I want to load content from file mentioned in `$ReadMeFilePath.FullName` path.

While executing, this throws an exception:
`Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "File format is not valid."

At line:1 char:30

+ $PatchSummaryTextBox.LoadFile <<<< ($ReadMeFilePath.FullName)

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Output of `$ReadMeFilePath.FullName` is
D:\Work\HotfixHandling Testing\V03.02.01 Hotfixes\V03.02.01P9\Readme.txt
which is correct path.

Can anyone suggest what could be possible reason for exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `RichTextBox.LoadFile(string path)` [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you pass a path to a RTF file. A file called `Readme.txt` is likely to be plain text. As per documentation:

> With this version of the LoadFile method, if the file being loaded is
>   not an RTF document, an exception will occur. To load a different type
>   of file such as an ASCII text file, use the other versions of this
>   method that accept a value from the RichTextBoxStreamType enumeration
>   as a parameter

As for a solution, use [overloaded version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d76176b1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that supports plain text files.